# How to prevent printing predict_proba() output in Keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I am using `predict_proba()` in Keras for thousand of times, and after each use it prints the following:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s
```

I wonder how I can prevent it from printing this. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `verbose=0` to `predict_proba` to turn off verbose output.